# GCC predefined macros for architecture X

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, predefined-macro

I have googled for a list of predefined macros per architecture used by gcc without success. Is there such a list or do I need to -dM for crosscompilers.

Comment: @BrettHale . This is an answer

Comment: There's an effort to maintain such a list [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/). Consider contributing if you have any more up to date results...