# How to tell if program is running on x86/x64 or ARM Linux platforms

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

In a `c` program I want to do different things. This program will run on x86/x64 based GNU/Linux system as well as ARM based one e.g. on a PC or RaspberryPI.

Is there predefined macros in GCC to tell the platform?

something like

```
#ifdef _X64_
   /do x64 stuff
#elif _ARM_
//do arm stuff
#endif
```

Or maybe that is the wrong approach? I will be using `Makefile`to compile and I could get away with my own defines.

What would be the best/safest approach?

Comment: not "run" but "compiled for". Yes, this is right approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860850/gcc-predefined-macros-for-architecture-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting CPU architecture compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152016/detecting-cpu-architecture-compile-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has already been answered on these posts:
[GCC predefined macros for architecture X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860850/gcc-predefined-macros-for-architecture-x), [Detecting CPU architecture compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152016/detecting-cpu-architecture-compile-time)

You can have them here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Architectures/

Your approach should only be used for small portions of code or functions but it should work.

**Edit:**
Basically, because links can become invalid:
`__arm__` should work on ARM.
`__x86_64__` should work on x64 architecture.

And yes, you can do:

```
#ifdef __x86_64__    
    // do x64 stuff   
#elif __arm__    
    // do arm stuff
#endif
```

Comment: This answers the question sufficiently. Inlining content from the linked page only makes it more likely the answer will be obsolete some day.